# Jest unable to mock a function inside FC

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I need to spy on the function 'fetchPosts' to write unit test to check it is being triggered.

I am new to jest world, would appreciate the help.

> **Component:**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPostAction } from '../../actions/postsAction';

const Button = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const fetchPosts = () => {
        dispatch(fetchPostAction());
    };

    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => fetchPosts()}
            className="btn btn-primary "
            data-test="Button">
            Fetch posts
        </button>
    );
};

export default Button;
```

I want a way to spy on that function and simulate it for unit test

> **Test:**

```js
describe('Button Component', () => {
    let component;
    let spy;
    let mockFetchPosts = jest.fn();
    beforeEach(() => {
        component = setup();
        spy = jest.spyOn(Button, 'fetchPosts');
        spy.mockReturnValue(mockFetchPosts);
    });

    it('Should render without failing', () => {
        const buttonComponent = findByTestAttr(component, 'Button');
        expect(buttonComponent.length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('Should dispatch action when clicked', () => {
        const buttonComponent = findByTestAttr(component, 'Button');
        buttonComponent.simulate('click');
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // failing 
    });
});
```

> **Error:**

`Cannot spy the fetchPosts property because it is not a function; undefined given instead`

Comment: I think you need to do `import { fetchPostAction } from '../../actions/postsAction';` and `jest.spyOn(fetchPostAction)` in the test itself

Comment: How do I export a function from inside of my FC ?

Comment: I don't think you should. The function `fetchPosts` is internal to your component (kind of like a `private` member in a class) so when you unit test you shouldn't worry about the behaviour of that part normally.  You either need to test `Button` for the side-effects of calling the function correctly or check if `fetchPostAction` is dispatched which is what `fetchPosts` does itself. If you must export it you need to move it out of the component and pass `dispatch` as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

`Button.prototype.fetchPosts` is undefined, jest can't spy on an undefined value. Instead of `spy` fetchPosts you can spy the `axios` call or `fetchPostAction`function:

```
import axios from "axios";

jest.mock("axios");
axios.get = jest.fn(()=> Promise.resolve({}));

it('Should dispatch action when clicked', () => {
    const buttonComponent = findByTestAttr(component, 'Button');
    buttonComponent.simulate('click');
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Or:

```
import * as postActions from "../../actions/postsAction";
    
it("Should dispatch action when clicked", async () => {
  const spyPostAction = jest.spyOn(postActions, "fetchPostAction")
  const buttonComponent = findByTestAttr(component, "Button");
  buttonComponent.simulate("click");
  expect(spyPostAction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Both are failing with same error: 

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Can you review it? It's here

https://github.com/karankumarshreds/ReactTDD/tree/master/src/components/Button

Comment: I update my answer, I saw you are using axios, in this case it is much better to check if axios.get is being called.

Comment: Or spy fetchPostAction action